# Lua - How to print 2 things in one print statement

Tags: lua, roblox

In python you are able to print 2 things by using one statement by typing

`print("Hello" + " World")`

Output would be `"Hello world"`

So is there a simple to do this again in Lua?

I'm trying to make the statement print the percentage and the percentage sign. This is currently what I have

```
function update()
    local hp = crysHu.Health/ crysHu.MaxHealth
    local text = script.Parent.TextLabel
    healthBar:TweenSize(UDim2.new(hp,0,1,0),"In","Linear",1)
    text.Text = math.floor(hp*100)
end
```

`text.Text = math.floor(hp*100)` is the part that I need help with FYI.

doing `text.Text = (math.floor(hp*100) + "%"`) doesn't work.

Comment: I removed the Python tag as you are looking for an answer in Lua.

Comment: Please refer to the Lua Reference Manual so you don't have to ask about the very basics of Lua here. That's what manuals are written for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing simple string manipulations, you can concatenate them with `..` like this :

```
local foo = 100
print( tostring(foo) .. "%") -- 100%
```

or if you want more specific formatting you can use `string.format`

```
local foo = 100
print( string.format("%d%%", foo)) -- 100%
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `,`. Its the same for both Lua and Python though Lua puts a tab between them in a `print`:

```lua
print(2, 3) # 2   3
```

or use `io.write` but then you need to handle the newline.

```
io.write("hello", " world\n") # hello world
```